# AppleScript: How can i hide an applescript-program from the desktop while it is running?

Tags: applescript

My appleScript-program runs several minutes and I don't wont see the script running. Can I hide it from the desktop a appleScript-command at the beginning of the program

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "AppleScript-program" you mean an AppleScript app: an AppleScript saved as an application to run independently of Script Editor.  If that's the case, the you want to set the [LSUIElement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/lsuielement) property of the app to 'true'. There are two ways to do this:

1. Manually edit the Application's info.plist file

   1. Locate the AppleScript app icon in the Finder
   2. Right-click on the icon and choose "Show Package Contents"
   3. Open the "Contents" folder that appears
   4. Open the "info.plist" file in a plain-text editor (like BBEdit or TextEdit")
   5. Check to make sure there isn't an 'LSUIElement' key in the plist
   6. Add the following key-value pair to the plist, or edit one that's there, without breaking up any other key-value pairs:

   > ```
   > <key>LSUIElement</key>
   > <true/>
   > ```
2. Use terminal to set the value

   1. Open Terminal.app (or an equivalent command-line application)
   2. Type in the following command, and execute:

   > ```
   > defaults write /Path/to/YourScriptApp.app/Contents/Info LSUIElement 1
   > ```

Both methods produce the same outcome, so do whichever you're more comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But No my appleScript-program is not an app. Its a .scrpt-program

Comment: Do you meant an AppleScript application made in Xcode? Then you can just set LSUIElement to true in Xcode, in the **info** section of the project settings. Unless you're doing something extremely odd your app is going to be a package, and the package folder will have an info.plist file. That's how these things work.

Comment: Sorry the program-name is: program.scpt, thats a normal "AppleScript-Script" - program.

Comment: And you're running it from the script editor? If you run it from the Script Menu it will run invisibly in the background. Or you could just (you know) hide Script Editor using ⌘-H.